mojoでpythonの組み込み関数を使いたい場合どうしたらいいですか？
mojoでnumpyなどのmoduleをimportして使用する方法は、
公式などにも書かれていますが、pythonの組み込み関数を使う場合、
どうしたらいいのか調べても出てきません。
mojo独自の組み込み関数も増えてきていますが、pythonとは仕様が異なるようです。
例えばpythonのabs()関数　を呼び出す方法はありますか？

あてずっぽで builtins というモジュールを呼び出してみたらできました。
マニュアルのどこに書いているのかはわかりませんが。
実行例:
var built_in_functions =Python.import_module("builtins") 
print(built_in_functions.abs(-10))

実行結果:
10

